# SignalR random 403

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I use SingalR in a ASP.net web. I use Active Directory for authentication, but a single page must use anonymous authentication.

The following page is allowed only for "operario" user group. It also uses signalR for websockets connections.

If I disable completely Anonymous authentication, SignalR works. But if I enable it, strange things happens: sometimes the connection is dropped and doesn't reconnect, sometimes pressing F5 doesn't reconnects, but sometimes it reconnects perfectly.

This is the chrome network page showing error connecting to signalR. This particular page requires user to be logged in in Active Directory to access.

[image: 403]

I "feel" like somehow the request to SignalR is being done as anonymous and therefore it responds with 403 maybe? why does this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Having the same random issue.

Comment: Have you ever figured out what was wrong here? I am having the same issue. :\

Comment: IIRC this error happened on dev but not on pre-production environment so it might be related to a misconfiguration on my dev environment. But can't tell for sure.